# Angular with Nginx and docker-compose

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, dockerfile, nginx-config

I'm trying to run with Docker compose an angular app. This is my Dockerfile of Angular container

```yaml
# Stage 0, for downloading project’s npm dependencies, building and compiling the app.
FROM node:14.13 as node

# set working directory
RUN mkdir /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# add .bin to $PATH
ENV PATH /usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# install package.json (o sea las dependencies)
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/package.json
RUN npm install
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli@10.0.3 

# add app
COPY . /usr/src/app

# start app
CMD npm build-prod

# Stage 1, for copying the compiled app from the previous step and making it ready for production with Nginx
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY --from=node /usr/src/app/dist/bloomingfrontend /usr/share/nginx/html/
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

docker-compose file:

```yaml
version: '3.3'

services:
  web: 
    build: './blooming_frontend'
    ports: 
      - 80:80
    depends_on:
      - spring
  spring:
    build: ./blooming_backend
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
```

And nginx.conf

```json
server {

    server_name localhost;
    listen      80;
    root        /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index       index.html index.htm;

    location / {

        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;

    }

}
```

As I seem in some tutorials it's fine to work, but when accessing localhost throws
The localhost page has rejected the connection.

I'm new with Nginx and I dont know what I have to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your nginx configuration the `localhost` matches the container not the host (nginx will only accepts connections from the container itself).
Removing the `server_name` line should make it works.

Answer (score 0):

For the case that somebody gets here.

For me, besides of changing the node **version to 16.10** in the first line, this line did the trick:

`RUN npm run build` (instead of CMD npm build-prod)